# Trying to convert address string to type address in Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am trying to convert address string to type address in solidity but when I am doing

```
    function StringToBytes(string memory _str) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        return bytes(_str);
        
    }
    function StringToBytesLength(string memory _str) public pure returns (uint256) {
        return bytes(_str).length;
        
    }
```

The result of StringToBytes is giving me 42 which should ideally gives me 20. If I am trying the same thing in python i.e convert string to bytes , it is giving me 20 bytes which is the length of an ethereum address in bytes. I had found several solutions to convert address string to address type but none of them is working for solidity version 0.7.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I want a solution but it is not optimal, I am looking for a solution which is lighter on gas fees, It is now consuming 77492.

```
    function fromHexChar(uint8 c) public pure returns (uint8) {
        if (bytes1(c) >= bytes1('0') && bytes1(c) <= bytes1('9')) {
            return c - uint8(bytes1('0'));
        }
        if (bytes1(c) >= bytes1('a') && bytes1(c) <= bytes1('f')) {
            return 10 + c - uint8(bytes1('a'));
        }
        if (bytes1(c) >= bytes1('A') && bytes1(c) <= bytes1('F')) {
            return 10 + c - uint8(bytes1('A'));
        }
        return 0;
    }
    
    function hexStringToAddress(string calldata s) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        bytes memory ss = bytes(s);
        require(ss.length%2 == 0); // length must be even
        bytes memory r = new bytes(ss.length/2);
        for (uint i=0; i<ss.length/2; ++i) {
            r[i] = bytes1(fromHexChar(uint8(ss[2*i])) * 16 +
                        fromHexChar(uint8(ss[2*i+1])));
        }

        return r;

    }
    
    function toAddress(string calldata s) public pure returns (address) {
        bytes memory _bytes = hexStringToAddress(s);
        require(_bytes.length >= 1 + 20, "toAddress_outOfBounds");
        address tempAddress;

        assembly {
            tempAddress := div(mload(add(add(_bytes, 0x20), 1)), 0x1000000000000000000000000)
        }

        return tempAddress;
    }
```

Comment: The ideal solution is to write your smart contract in a way that they do not deal with strings. Only very few cases you need to store strings on-chain and in fewer cases you need to process them. So the fact strings are processed in Solidity means that there are flaws in the smart contract architecture of the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract StringToAddress {

function stringToAddress(string memory _address) public pure returns (address) {
    string memory cleanAddress = remove0xPrefix(_address);
    bytes20 _addressBytes = parseHexStringToBytes20(cleanAddress);
    return address(_addressBytes);
}

function remove0xPrefix(string memory _hexString) internal pure returns (string memory) {
    if (bytes(_hexString).length >= 2 && bytes(_hexString)[0] == '0' && (bytes(_hexString)[1] == 'x' || bytes(_hexString)[1] == 'X')) {
        return substring(_hexString, 2, bytes(_hexString).length);
    }
    return _hexString;
}

function substring(string memory _str, uint256 _start, uint256 _end) internal pure returns (string memory) {
    bytes memory _strBytes = bytes(_str);
    bytes memory _result = new bytes(_end - _start);
    for (uint256 i = _start; i < _end; i++) {
        _result[i - _start] = _strBytes[i];
    }
    return string(_result);
}

function parseHexStringToBytes20(string memory _hexString) internal pure returns (bytes20) {
    bytes memory _bytesString = bytes(_hexString);
    uint160 _parsedBytes = 0;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _bytesString.length; i += 2) {
        _parsedBytes *= 256;
        uint8 _byteValue = parseByteToUint8(_bytesString[i]);
        _byteValue *= 16;
        _byteValue += parseByteToUint8(_bytesString[i + 1]);
        _parsedBytes += _byteValue;
    }
    return bytes20(_parsedBytes);
}

function parseByteToUint8(bytes1 _byte) internal pure returns (uint8) {
    if (uint8(_byte) >= 48 && uint8(_byte) <= 57) {
        return uint8(_byte) - 48;
    } else if (uint8(_byte) >= 65 && uint8(_byte) <= 70) {
        return uint8(_byte) - 55;
    } else if (uint8(_byte) >= 97 && uint8(_byte) <= 102) {
        return uint8(_byte) - 87;
    } else {
        revert(string(abi.encodePacked("Invalid byte value: ", _byte)));
    }
}
}
```